# Benefactor badge awarded twice

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, bounty-badges

The description of the Benefactor badge indicates that it is a non-recurring badge: *"First bounty you manually awarded on your own question"*. However, at tex.sx, user Raphink was awarded the Benefactor badge *twice* [(link)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/47/benefactor?userid=951):

[image]

A possible reason is that Raphink awarded his first two bounties on one of his own questions *within one second* (see the time stamp popup in the link).

Comment: Raphink apparently has the FGITW when it comes to awarding bounties. He deserves the second badge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've pushed a change for the next build that'll prevent this, it was incorrectly grouping distinct awards *including* PostId (for the reason, once that was added)...which obviously doesn't work so well.

The user has been corrected as well.  Not rushing a build for this since I'm out the door in a few...but it's so incredibly rare I don't think it'll hurt to wait.

Comment: Noticed another user having 2 benefactor badges. But yes, it was long ago.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/221/benefactor?userid=648865